# Clear a class within a method

Tags: c++, c++11

I want a function of the class that I have to clear the class before it applies its function without having to manually do it every time I ask the function of that class in a loop using the default constructor (as I do now).

An example

```
class Hello
{
 public:
 std::vector<int> a,b,c; //,d,e,... etc...

 void set ( int value )
 {
  a.push_back(value);
  b.push_back(value);  
  c.push_back(value); 
  //d.push_back...
  //e.push_back...
  //etc...

  return;
 }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Hello &hello)
{
 for ( int i=0; i<hello.a.size(); i++ )
 {
  os << hello.a[i] << "\t";
  os << hello.b[i] << "\t";
  os << hello.c[i] << "\t";
  //etc...
  os << std::endl;
 }
 os << std::endl;

 return os;
}
```

Somewhere in main

```
Hello hello;

for ( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
{
 hello = Hello(); //want to get rid of this line and move its functionality to the set function

 hello.set(i);
 std::cout << hello << std::endl;
}
```

This will produce the correct result, however if I remove the line that clears the variable ( hello = Hello() ) then the set function will keep on appending to the vector and not clear the vector before it appends to it.

So basically I want to not worry about having to type the line hello = Hello(), every time I loop over the set function. By incorporating this clearing of the variable inside the set function of the class itself.

Typing a.clear(), b.clear() etc... before the push_back functions could work but with many vectors that would be a lot of lines. I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you have `std::array<std::vector<int>, 5u> vecs;` instead of `std::vector<int>  a, b, c, d, e` ?

Comment: Why not just declare `hello` in the loop?  Then it is default constructed (empty) each iteration automatically.

Comment: Could you have an inner loop and loop over the elements in your vector clearing each one?

Comment: OK, so just put `*this = Hello();` in the first line of `set`?

Comment: @Jarod42 In practise a, b, c etc... are real things like x-coordinate, number of contacts etc... that have a meaning, so I prefer to call to those as well by their names

Comment: @melpomene cool that works, thanks

Comment: I would suggest you the same as @NathanOliver, declare the object inside the loop, so there is no need to "clear" it. With the solution you get when calling `*this = Hello();` you are just hiding the fact that in each iteration the constructor is called, while if you do `for (;;) { Hello hello; ... }` you get a clear object on each iteration, no extra work required and the fact that the constructor is called is clearly visible in the code